# Recursively listing of files and folders in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures, file-io, recursion, .net-4.0

I wrote this code to recursively list files and folders in c#.

```
            var filesInTheCurrentDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(rootFolder);
            if (!filesInTheCurrentDirectory.Any() && !System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(rootFolder).ToList().Any())
            {
                return;
            }

            filesInTheCurrentDirectory.ToList().ForEach(file => System.IO.File.AppendAllText("e:\\personal\\tests.txt", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file) + ":" + rootFolder + "\n"));
            System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(rootFolder).ToList().ForEach(recursivePrintFolders);
```

While this just ***works great***, the question is:

1. I am using recursion. Is this way the **`best`** ? (I tried writing a non-recursive function but stuck up because **we do not know what is the depth of each folder** in advance).
2. How to evaluate the performance of this function ? Is it `OlogN` or `O(n)` ? (I am confused because there is no looping version. According to me, if there is two `for` loops, i can just call it `O(n^2)`.)

Any ideas or guidance's ?

Comment: Why not just use the [overload of the method you're using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx) that handles this for you?

Comment: Can you post your non-recursive function?

Comment: @DanPuzey Correction: That is overload :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: corrected! Mondays... ;-)

Comment: This would be better in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @liquidsnake786: as i said, i was stuck up writing a non-recursive function because i did not know the depth of each directory. thats why

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: just another way of writing this code with a better performance ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed: there are non-recursive ways of writing this...

Comment: @DanPuzey: Thanks for the `overload`. But, can you guide me with measuring the performance of my function ? Also, the overload seems to help with finding a file but not for printing all the files within a folder.

Comment: What is `n`? If that's the number of files + number of folders, then yeah, O(n) sounds about right (you do a constant amount of work for every file / folder).

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. Are you displeased with the performance of the code that you wrote? Do you have or envision having a directory structure so deep as to trigger a stack overflow? Of course this code is not going to work in the presence of NTFS links that introduce back loops into your directory hierarchy, but this is not going to be fixed by a non-recursive implementation without doing some additional changes.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: No, the code works just good as it should be. Also, i do ont envision having a directory structure so deep for an overflow. Thanks for the tips. :)

Comment: @User3805967 It's not going to be changed to be iterative automatically...

Comment: @Dukeling: Thanks. O(n) fits for the performance.

Comment: @User3805967 You're the one asserting that it is going to do that.  Why don't you provide proof that it will automatically convert all recursive methods into iterative methods for you.  I don't need to link to MSDN for proof though.  Just call the method `void Foo(){Foo();Console.Write('a');}`  If it throws a stack overflow exception it's recursive, if it just runs forever then it was translated into an iterative solution automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problems with using recursion to do this is:

1. If your tree has a depth that is too large you may not have enough stack space.  While it would be uncommon to have that deep of a file system structure, it's not inconceivable.
2. You are using more memory than needed, in that you're holding onto a lot of data in stack frames that you could potentially avoid.

As for the asymptotic complexity, you're performing one operation per node, regardless of it's size, so it's O(n), where n is all nodes, not the nodes at any given depth.

However, you can handle all of this much more effectively using the built in method to traverse the entire tree.  It is going to be more efficient than a solution you'll come up with, even if yours is non-recursive, just use:

```
foreach(string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("e:\\personal\\tests.txt",
        System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file) + ":" + rootFolder + "\n")
}
```

While that solution is likely not to use recursion, if you want to know how to write a non-recursive tree traversal yourself, you can use a general purpose method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source
    , Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>(source);
    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        yield return next;
        foreach (var child in childrenSelector(next))
            stack.Push(child);
    }
}
```

In your case calling it could look something like this:

```
var allFiles = new[] { new DirectoryInfo(path) }
    .Traverse(directory => directory.EnumerateDirectories())
    .Select(directory => directory.EnumerateFiles());
```

Note that, while this is fine for traversing a tree that doesn't provide a built in way for a full traversal, this is generally not ideal for traversing the file system.  You should use the first solution in that it has been highly optimized already for the special case of traversing a file system.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance. Exactly answers. But, sorry, I still did not understand this part of your answer. `you're performing one operation per node, regardless of it's size, so it's O(n)`. can you kindly elaborate it for me ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. What else is there to say.  The amount of work is directly proportional to the number of nodes in the whole tree.  A tree with 2x as many nodes will take 2x as long to traverse.  Adding a single node to a tree of size 100 vs a tree of size 5 adds the same "cost".  That makes it linear.

Comment: Thanks. Not it makes sense. Also, the `generic non-recursive` version just works great.

Comment: +1 for the good answer ;)

Comment: Iirc, the built-in directory enumerations fail for a folder you don't have security permissions for. So e.g. `Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` will fail for a non-elevated program for a user with UAC enabled (it won't let it get into C:\System, amongst other things). To enumerate all directories that you have permission for, you will need to walk the tree with your own code, and check permissions at each stage.