# Directory (File-Folder) manipulation using a tree in c#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures, tree

People talk about `trees` and yes, I can understand the concepts of `tree` and the ways `traversing` it `conceptually`. It is also interesting that in a `binary search tree` the search time is `O(log N)`.

Now, I have certain `folders in my system` whose file-structure is `not going to be modified` except that the `new files are added often`.

I can visualize that if I build a binary search tree representing the folder structure I can very well search using the file-name in `O(log N)`. I know that this can be done very efficiently with the built-in .NET methods, but I am trying to see a real life use case scenario of using the tree.

The MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379573%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) tells that `'Trees are common data structures because many real-world problems exhibit tree-like behavior. For example, any sort of hierarchical relationship among people, things, or objects can be modeled as a tree.` but, the problem is that i cannot model the above requirement to a tree ?

The question is this:

`I cannot visualize how to connect the BST concept and my requirement`. Every binary tree sample I see , just explains by adding some simple integers to the nodes and traverses it.

1. How to build the tree for a directory traversal ? (Please- some code or pseudo-code, not just theory answers again!)
2. How to store the already built tree ?

(As for as getting all the files from my folder structure, I use my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196395/recursively-listing-of-files-and-folders-in-c-sharp))

Comment: SO is not the place for this kind of question.  The FAQ will help you to choose the right questions for this site.  I'd try Programmers.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are fundamentally confusing two unrelated concepts. A tree is a data structure that has a hierarchical structure associated with it. A binary search tree is a data structure that is a tree, but with significantly more restrictions on its shape. Each node must have zero, one, or two children. Each node stores some key in it, and the tree has the property that for each node, all keys in nodes in its left subtree are less than the original node's key and all keys in nodes in its right subtree are greater than the original node's key.

While you can use some trickery to represent a directory tree as a binary search tree, it would be misguided to do so because it's the wrong tool for the job. A directory tree can have an arbitrarily large branching factor and is not stored in any sorted order. I would recommend starting off by doing some reading on general trees, not just binary search trees, to get a better sense for the distinction and for more information on how to represent an arbitrary tree structure.

As for how to actually build up the tree - you might want to look into the depth-first search or breadth-first search algorithms, which would probably be excellent candidates for exploring the directory structures and building up the directory trees.

Hope this helps!